# How to import Romanian diacritics from csv to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv, diacritics

i have found one error on my script.
While is importing from csv file to MySQL database diacritics shown strange char.

i need fast and realiable solution in SQL query in my code below:

```
$sql = "INSERT into medici (`cnp`, `cod_parafa`, `tit_id`, `numele`, `numele_anterior`,...
```

what i need is importing fields: numele and numele_anterior with support my romanian char like șțăîâ.
My database has set utf8_romanian_ci char.

Comment: You probably mean utf8, not utf9. Did you tell the PHP script that your database is UTF-8 (`$link->set_charset("utf8");`)? Did you check the encoding of the csv file (e.g., in Notepad++)? If your csv file comes from Excel, the encoding is probably not UTF-8.

Comment: i tried export as utf8, iso8859-2 (eastern europe), Latin 1 but i get the same strange chars. i tried also to edit in gedit to change chars...same error - i'm stuck

Comment: It may help to give an example of the strange characters. For example, if you read UTF-8 șțăîâ as ANSI, you get È™È›ÄƒÃ®Ã¢. Does that look familiar?